# Radwindow on dropdown selected indexchange

Tags: asp.net, telerik, popup

I am trying to get a pop-up window(Rad Window) with a text box and button, when a user selects a particular item in the telerik radcombobox.

Please suggest some tips/telerik samples if anyone came across this requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured out finally,we get radwindow on ddl selection as below

```
if (ddl.SelectedValue.ToString() == "n/a")
    {

        string script = "function f(){$find(\"" + RadWindow1.ClientID + "\").show();   Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", script, true);
    }
```